# MVC5 issuing a HTTPWebRequest and WebResponse take long time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to get date and time online using the following code

```
public static DateTime GetDate()
    {
        try
        {
            var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.microsoft.com");
            var response = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            var todaysDates = response.Headers["date"];
            var onlineDate = DateTime.ParseExact(todaysDates,
                "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat,
                DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
            return DateTime.Parse(onlineDate.ToString("d"));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return DateTime.Today;
        }

    }
```

This code working fine if called from Console application, but if a called this code from MVC5 it take very long time to response. Any idea

Comment: Did you debug the code? Where exactly in the code it takes long time?

Comment: var response = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();